# How do I use an object that is a session-scope fixture across classes in a pytest test suite?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, fixtures

EDIT: Removing unittest (python unit test) fixed my issue. Python unittest can cause your fixtures to fail if you are mixing pytest and unittest. I inherited from unittest.TestCase in my test class hierarchy.

I have my session scope fixture in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def test_client():
    <SETUP>
    client = Client(protocol)
    return client
```

And I would like to send requests to a TCP server using this fixture across several test classes:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixture('test_client')
class TestCases(BaseTest):
    ...
    def test_case_m(self, test_client):
        ....
        results = test_client.query("bananas")
    ....
```

**How do I define a session-scope fixture as an object and then how do I access said fixture within each class?**

I have tried a half-dozen combinations of decorators and used return/yield in the session scope fixture. Unfortunately, I cannot get seem to make the session-scope fixture available, cannot find any docs on pytest, nor previous stack overflow posts that address this. What is the proper pattern? How does pytest make the object available? I would really like to know the purpose of attaching decorators in pytest it seems like voodoo to me.

Comment: I believe `test_case_m` is supposed to be a test case in which case it should not be decorated with `@pytest.fixture`. I strongly suggest, take a good look at this [page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) and there are many examples to help you understand the fixtures, their scopes and in particular how to use a session scoped fixture in test functions in a class.

Comment: I did spend an hour reading that page again, but I am unable to solve my use case. However you are right, it should not be @pytest.fixture that is a decorator to mark a fixture factory function.

Comment: Once you remove the `@pytest.fixture` decorator, what error do you get?

Comment: It turns out that the base class using unittest was causing fixtures to fail. I removed unittest and the fixture is working fine using the above edited pattern.